# cakePHP "session" is not returning session ID

Tags: cakephp

I am into development of a cakePHP based web application.

Here are my core.php settings for session handling

```
  Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');
/**
 * The name of the table used to store CakePHP database sessions.
 *
 * 'Session.save' must be set to 'database' in order to utilize this constant.
 *
 * The table name set here should *not* include any table prefix defined elsewhere.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.table', 'cake_sessions');
/**
 * The DATABASE_CONFIG::$var to use for database session handling.
 *
 * 'Session.save' must be set to 'database' in order to utilize this constant.
 */
    //Configure::write('Session.database', 'default');
    Configure::write('Session.start', true); 
/**
 * The name of CakePHP's session cookie.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'CAKEPHP');
/**
 * Session time out time (in seconds).
 * Actual value depends on 'Security.level' setting.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.timeout', '300');
/**
 * If set to false, sessions are not automatically started.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.start', true);
/**
 * When set to false, HTTP_USER_AGENT will not be checked
 * in the session
 */
    Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);
/**
 * The level of CakePHP security. The session timeout time defined
 * in 'Session.timeout' is multiplied according to the settings here.
 * Valid values:
 *
 * 'high'   Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 10
 * 'medium' Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 100
 * 'low'        Session timeout in 'Session.timeout' x 300
 *
 * CakePHP session IDs are also regenerated between requests if
 * 'Security.level' is set to 'high'.
```

CakePHP session id is always blank. although other session read/write activities are working perfectly fine.

Below is the session object.

```
SessionComponent Object
(
    [__active] => 1
    [__started] => 
    [__bare] => 0
    [valid] => 
    [error] => Array
        (
            [2] => Auth.redirect doesn't exist
        )

    [_userAgent] => 2abebfb51fc971ec64569f7cd415fe0b
    [path] => /
    [lastError] => 2
    [security] => high
    [time] => 1278950154
    [sessionTime] => 1278953154
    [watchKeys] => Array
        (
        )

    [id] => 
    [_log] => 
    [host] =>localhost
    [enabled] => 1
    [cookieLifeTime] => 0
)
```

All the other session variable are stored and retrieved properly, the problem is I am not getting session id at any stage.

Can you please help me what can be problem.

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: What are you trying to do with your Session ID? What's your motivation for using it?

Comment: What I want to do is, to post the session Id and some security token to a cakePHP action , and retrieve the session information using the session id and validating the security token.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the other Session storage types to see if its specific to the "DB" sessions? I assume you also created the Sessions DB table schema using the cake CLI? Also, has this ever worked properly? If so, what were some of the last steps you took before it broke?

Comment: yes,I have tried "cake" type , it works fine but dont give me session id (same case as with setting 'database')

Answer (score 2):

use `session_id()`
I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had such experience and it's not good at all. Check if any of the resources are missing. I.e. some images, css or js files could be missing and then Cake loads the missing controller/action page which could reset the session.

Comment: I checked that there are no missing resources ,I think the problem is somewhere else :(

Answer (score 0):

refer to [cakephp session id Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720012/cakephp-session-id-empty)

try to start the session with

```
$this->Session->start();
```