# cakephp session id Empty

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

The session id is empty when I do: `pr($this->Session);`
I receive :

```
SessionComponent Object
(
    [__active] => 1
    [__bare] => 0
    [valid] => 1
    [error] => 
    [_userAgent] => 5343528de22b8a6d25e7fd391692c911
    [path] => /profiles
    [lastError] => 
    [security] => medium
    [time] => 800-452-3639
    [sessionTime] => 800-452-3639
    [cookieLifeTime] => 720000
    [watchKeys] => Array
        (
        )

    [id] => 
    [host] => xyz.org
    [timeout] => 
    [enabled] => 1
)
```

How do I either enable the session id or make the session id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want a session id, you need to start the session. Try this in your before filter:

```
$this->Session->start();
$this->Session->id(session_id());
```

Then when you `pr($this->Session->id());` you will see the new session id.

Comment: Thanks for `session_id()`. I couldn't find it documented anywhere. Is starting the session really required? Does it automatically get started perhaps when I write to the session?

Answer (score 2):

It's passively taken care of by Cake - you don't need to set it.  Just make calls to read(), write() as needed.

```
$this->Session->write('key', $value);

$value = $this->Session->read('key');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

> echo $this->Session->id(); //prints like 7gl7bo9gv38rj0sjtqo52dkeu5

in controller. There is no need to start() or something else. Cakephp (tested in 2.7) automatically makes it available for you.